# LinAlgError: Singular matrix while using np.linalg.solve()

Tags: python

Does anybody know how to solve the linear equation including a singular matrix?

```
z_k1 = np.linalg.solve(M, w_k)
```

M is a square matrix and w_k is a vector. It seems that the M matrix I get is a singular matrix. But I have to solve this equation. Is there another way to solve equation?

Comment: If the matrix is singular means that there's either no solution or infinitely many solutions. Better check that you matrix is correct. Alternatively, try finding the optimal solution using least squares `np.linalg.lstsq`.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!